# django-tailwind: doesnt start upon running 'python manage.py tailwind start'

Tags: python, django, django-tailwind

i followed the docs and it says that after the command 'python manage.py tailwind start'
the development server should start.

however im getting this and its stuck on the 'rebuilding phase' and doesnt continue

Node.js: v18.10.0
django: 4.2
django-tailwind: 4.5

```
> my_theme@3.5.0 start
> npm run dev


> my_theme@3.5.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w


Rebuilding...

Done in 1143ms.
```

anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The command is working fine. If you will make any changes to the html then it will rebuild the css again accordingly. So you need to keep this running in a terminal window and in a separate terminal window you can run the server with the following command: 'python manage.py runserver'

Answer (score -1):

the problem in template file in theme app remove it and make sure your templates file named as templates becuse tailwind confing is writen with default sittings of django project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).